# unable to get data in onActivityResult() in android on passing image URL

Tags: android

I want to upload multiple images through android application to firebase. I want to get the URL of the image which i got in my second activity(ie, B Activity) to my first activityIA activity). I have tried many answers posted but I could not solve the issue. Can anyone help me please. Here is my code

`B Activity`

```
      mSelectBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

                } });

        }


        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


            if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

                if(data.getClipData() != null){

                     totalItemsSelected = data.getClipData().getItemCount();

                    for(int i = 0; i < totalItemsSelected; i++){

                        Uri fileUri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();

                        String fileName = getFileName(fileUri);

                        fileNameList.add(fileName);
                        fileDoneList.add("uploading");
                        uploadListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        StorageReference fileToUpload = mStorage.child("Images").child(fileName);


                        final int finalI = i;
                        fileToUpload.putFile(fileUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                fileDoneList.remove(finalI);
                                fileDoneList.add(finalI, "done");
    uploadListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Uploaded Successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      ImageUploadInfo imageUploadInfo = new ImageUploadInfo(taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
                                imageURL=imageUploadInfo.getImageURL();
                                imagesList.add(imageURL);
   Intent idata = new Intent()
                               idata.putExtra("imageURL", imageURL);

                                idata.putExtra("count",totalItemsSelected);

                                setResult(RESULT_OK, idata);
                                finish();

                            }
                        });

                    }
```

`A activity`

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       switch (resultCode) {
           case 1:
           if (requestCode == 123) {
               if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                   imageURL = data.getStringExtra("imageURL");
                   this.orderItem.setImageURL(imageURL);

               }
               if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                   //Write your code if there's no result
               }
           }
           break;

           case 2://added24
               if(requestCode==100){//added24
                   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                       imageURL = data.getStringExtra("imageURL");
                       newString=data.getStringExtra("count");

                   }

               }
               break;
       }

 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.order_item_update, menu);


        FrameLayout image_viewCount = (FrameLayout) menu.findItem(R.id.star).getActionView();

        TextView image_count = (TextView) image_viewCount.findViewById(R.id.cart_badge);
        image_count.setText(newString);


        image_viewCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MultipleActivity.class);
           Order.getInstance().getOrderItems();
                startActivityForResult(intent,100);

            }
        });
```

I want to set  the count (ie, "total selected" in image_count) but I am not able to get the value as I am not getting the value from Bactivity to A activity

Comment: are `BActivity` and `MultipleActivity` same?

Comment: So you are getting the count in B activity?

Comment: As I understand, the `MultipleActivity` is your `BActivity`, right ?

Comment: Yes MultipleActivity is my B activity @shinilms

Comment: Yes. I am getting my count in B activity@m__

Comment: Yes. They are same@KhalidTaha

Comment: not getting@shinilms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the `onActivityResult` in your `A` activity to,

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 123:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                imageURL = data.getStringExtra("imageURL");
                this.orderItem.setImageURL(imageURL);

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //Write your code if there's no result
            }
            break;

        case 100:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                imageURL = data.getStringExtra("imageURL");
                newString = data.getStringExtra("count");
            } else {
                //Write your code if there's no result
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

You were switching `resultCode` and the cases you used were `1` and `2`. The `int` constant for `RESULT_OK` is `-1`.

And in your `MultipleActivity` activity, the condition `data.getClipData() != null` will only be `true` when there are multiple `Uri`s to send back. When there is just one you can get it with `getData`. You can do it like this

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if (data.getClipData() != null) {
            totalItemsSelected = data.getClipData().getItemCount();

            for (int i = 0; i < totalItemsSelected; i++) {
                Uri fileUri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                String fileName = getFileName(fileUri);

                fileNameList.add(fileName);
                fileDoneList.add("uploading");
                uploadListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                StorageReference fileToUpload = mStorage.child("Images").child(fileName);

                final int finalI = i;
                fileToUpload.putFile(fileUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        fileDoneList.remove(finalI);
                        fileDoneList.add(finalI, "done");
                        uploadListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Uploaded Successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        ImageUploadInfo imageUploadInfo = new ImageUploadInfo(taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
                        imageURL = imageUploadInfo.getImageURL();
                        imagesList.add(imageURL);

                        Intent idata = new Intent();
                        idata.putExtra("imageURL", imageURL);
                        idata.putExtra("count", totalItemsSelected);
                        setResult(RESULT_OK, idata);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            Uri fileUri = data.getData();
            String fileName = getFileName(fileUri);

            fileNameList.add(fileName);
            fileDoneList.add("uploading");
            uploadListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            StorageReference fileToUpload = mStorage.child("Images").child(fileName);

            fileToUpload.putFile(fileUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    fileDoneList.remove(0);
                    fileDoneList.add(0, "done");
                    uploadListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Uploaded Successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    ImageUploadInfo imageUploadInfo = new ImageUploadInfo(taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
                    imageURL = imageUploadInfo.getImageURL();
                    imagesList.add(imageURL);

                    Intent idata = new Intent();
                    idata.putExtra("imageURL", imageURL);
                    idata.putExtra("count", 1);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, idata);
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not getting @shinilms

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the fileToUpload is async and you are creating them in a loop; you close the current activity when one of those tasks ends (the first one). You can simulate a semaphore, to mark the completion of each fileToUpload tasks and store the result in it, and in the onSuccess method, just check if all task instances are completed before closing the current activity and passing the result (which should be an array of objects btw).

Answer (score 0):

As I understood:
Activity-A opens Activity-B using startActivityForResult.
and you want image url which you got in Activity-B to Activity-A via onActivityResult().

If so then,
you have to add your activity finish code in some action not into onActivityResult() of Activity-B.
Because adding it to onActivityResult() means you are waiting for the response of any Activity you open from Activity-B using startActivityForResult.